# Can I display two distinct tables for a model in the django admin interface, based on a boolean in that model table?

Tags: python, mysql, django, admin

I want to display two separate tables for a model when I go into the django admin interface based on a boolean in that model. For example in admin.py I have:

```
class MyModelsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('Name', 'user', 'sample', 'experiment', 'reported')
```

and 'reported' is a boolean. I would like to display two tables , reported and not reported. Is there a way to do this in my MyModelsAdmin class? Something like:

```
class MyModelsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('Name', 'user', 'sample', 'experiment', 'reported')

    if reported == True:
         ... display table with header Reported ...

    elif reported == False:
         ... display table with header Not Reported ...

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Why not use [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

Comment: I would like it to be always in two tables

Comment: what kind of reported variable is ? is it can be accessed via request.user.reported ?